# Why is the Git remote/origins/master branch detached?

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I have a strange git scenario:  I've been developing on master, and ive noticed that when my CI clones down and attempts to modify a git repository, it doesn't see "master" in the refspec.  Thus, the command

```
git checkout master
```

Fails.  To fix this (as i need my CI to commit some minor updates to master), I tried to do:

```
git checkout remotes/origin/master
```

However, that command results in a DETACHED head.  The final fix was that, rather than doing a checkout, I do `checkout -b` like so:

```
git checkout -b master
```

Which magically seems to "create" the master branch which (I thought already exists), and then all is right in the world.

My question is, thus: What is the difference between remotes/origin/master and the master created via `git checkout -b`?  Since I only have one remote, I would think they would be synonymous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remotes/origin/master` is just a remote-tracking branch, it keeps track of which commit the `master` branch on the remote `origin` is on. Branches created with `git checkout -b <branch>` are ***local*** branches, not remote-tracking branches. That is the difference.

However, when you clone a repo, a local `master` is usually created because that is usually the standard default branch from the original repo, unless the original repo is set up to use a different branch name as the default. Perhaps that is why you are able to re-create the `master` branch locally? You can check by running the following command:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

In this output, you'll see that `origin/HEAD`, which represents the default branch on the remote, points to `origin/master`.

Also, is your CI actually re-cloning the entire repo repeatedly? That seems really inefficient. I think most CI setups would just clone the repo once, and then pull or receive new changes.

Comment: Thanks, ive set it to reclone every time just to help isolate the cause of this issue, but your right in the next iteration we want to pull changes rather than clone a fresh repo every time.